# Container not valid for pod when using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm building a docker container to install some dependencies and do a tfplanPromptApply in since there isn't a build agent with terraform and awscli.

Jenkins is giving me the following error: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: container tf-aws-buildagent:latest is not valid for pod name_of_pod.

Below is my code that installs builds the docker container. I then try to use the docker container to do a tfplanPromptApply from.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
stage("Docker Build") {
      steps {
        dockerSh containerCmd: "docker build -t containerName ."
      }
    }
    stage("Terraform Plan") {
      environment {
        TF_VAR_aws_environment="${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
        //CONTAINER_NAME="containerName"
      }
      steps {
        //dockerSh containerCmd: "docker build -t containerName ."

        tfPlanPromptApply tfContainerName: "containerName",
          tfSkipApply: true,
          tfDirPath: "terraform",
          tfStateBucket: "${config.terraform.statefile_bucket}",
          tfStateBucketRegion: "${config.aws.region}",
          teamsWebhook: "${webhookUrl}",
          githubCredentialsId: "${config.credentials.github}",
          awsCredentialsId: "${config.credentials.aws}"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is your pipeline running inside a docker agent ? I think you need to declare a docker container as a Jenkins agent and then use it in your steps to create your docker image example: (container('my-jenkins-docker-agent') { // steps } )